# How to print heart rate and stepcount data from the watch in Tizen Native?

Tags: c, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I want to fetch the step count and heart rate data from my Samsung Galaxy Watch 3 into a variable in Tizen Native. I have gone through the documentation and was able to find a sample code for reading the sensor data. So far i could read the accelerometer. But i want to read the heart rate data and stepcount. I'm running Tizen Studio with API 5.5 in Native.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Health data, you need to use SHealth SDK(https://developer.samsung.com/health). but, it supports only Android.